# Why should one encrypt a function in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I am reading that functions can be encrypted. under what circumstances we need this feature? I have used oracle for many years at my work place. Never thought about this feature. How and when should we be encrypting User defined functions?

CREATE FUNCTION testFunction ()
RETURNS int
WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
BEGIN
RETURN 1
END

Comment: I've never found a use case for this. I think it was originally to protect IP but the server admin can decrypt them so it is not useful for this.

Comment: to prevent any accidental or unauthorized modification of the object. Also to ensure any modification required is from the Source depository and not conveniently change on the DB

Comment: @Squirrel, no, no and no. Neither of those cases can be circumvented by object's encryption.

Comment: it many cases i have seen, yes yes & yes

Comment: There are no additional permissions required to alter an encrypted object, compared to a non-encrypted one. Don't see how it protects anything. Besides, encrypted objects cannot be published via replication.

Comment: I mean, if you really expect people here to gobble up an incendiary statement like this, it might make sense to elaborate your point of view. Probably as an answer.

Comment: @Squirrel the correct way to do this is of course to use permissions so only authorised accounts can make changes and have a proper release process / pipeline but I can see this might discourage casual changes if you are working in an environment without these in place.

Comment: @Squirrel -- I think Martin and Roger are correct.  Encryption does not prevent unauthorized access -- that is what permissions are for.  The intent of encryption is to protect I.P., but its nearly useless.  Through Sql 2005, it was completely useless because it could be hacked in 30 seconds.  Now, it might take 3 minutes after an Internet search.